# Adding a Post Notice to a flagged post should treat the flag as "handled" in the review queue

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

When I add a post notice to a flagged post in the review queue, the flagged posts stays in the  queue. It shouldn't, because putting the notice was obviously the flag handling action then. Keeping it in the queue just increases the likelihood that another mod will double handle it prematurely.

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4869916

The question was flagged as *Not An Answer* three times. And rightfully so given our standards. I could simply delete it (which is the common practise) or put the post notice and give the OP a chance to improve it. Both actions are handling the flags but only deleting would mark the flags as handled. I can obviously mark the flags as helpful after putting the notice (and I did in this case) but I shouldn't need to. Also, when I mark the flags as helpful, it needs another flag to bring it back to our attention. Ideally, the post could automatically pop back to the queue after a week. If the post wasn't improved by then, we can still delete it to maintain our quality standards.

Comment: I agree with the general premise, but converting it to a comment or deleting it would have been a better in that particular situation.  A post notice on a two-year-old answer isn't really going to inspire action.  That said, the other answer on that question falls in the same category.  Also, that *particular* post notice is usually for somewhat non-constructive questions that could use the benefit of a long answer ("good subjective/bad subjective" doesn't really apply here).

Comment: @casperOne if it's not inspiring action, it'll be deleted. This particular OP might not have an incentive to save his 20 points, but [this one might have](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882490/get-the-current-url-within-a-django-template/2882511#2882511). Anyways, I'd prefer not to discuss the concrete example but rather the suggested feature as such.

Comment: If you have the time to keep track of these that you've put post notices on, that's great, but I've generally found that not to be the case.